# Sorting array by length

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm wanting to sort this array by length but how will I do that?  I searched the web for a while but couldn't find anything.  The code is supposed to sort an array given at random by each strings length in the string array, but I can't get anyway of declaring how I want it to sort.

```
public class Kata
{
  public static string[] SortByLength (string[] array)
  {
    Array.Sort(array);
    return array;
  }
}
```

Comment: what you want is [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in order to sort the `array` *in place* you should provide *rule* of sorting:

```
  Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));
```

The method can be

```
  public static string[] SortByLength (string[] array) {
    //TODO: validate array and its items here; they must be not null

    Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));

    return array;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use linq...

```cs
public static string[] SortByLength (string[] array) =>
    array.OrderBy( x => x?.Length ?? 0 ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, this is how it should work.

```
Array.Sort(array, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Does not sort by length